# voltar a executar a função através do mesmo botão

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Ola

eu tenho um script para os markers da google que funciona assim:

eu tenho uma função que lê o json, lê os select, vê qual ou quais são as opções seleccionadas no select dentro do HTML, apaga os markers (que são todos) que já estão marcados e marca os que estão seleccionados.

isso tudo após clicar no botão de filtrar o problema que está a dar é que se eu mudar as opções seleccionadas **sem** dar refresh na pagina, não executa a função e coloca no mapa todos os markers que estão no json.

eu queria saber o que precisava de por na função para que eu possa **mudar as opções seleccionadas** e após clicar no botão outra vez executa a função toda de novo.

Script da função do meu botão de filtrar:

```js
function botao() {
    var filtroFaixaEtaria = $("#FaixaEtaria option:selected").text();
    var filtroSexo = $("#Sexo option:selected").text();
    var filtroRecursoArma = $("#RecursoArma option:selected").text();
    var filtroDistrito = $("#Distrito option:selected").text();

    var arrayResultados = jsondata.filter(function (item) {
        var criteria = true;

        if (filtroFaixaEtaria != null && filtroFaixaEtaria != "")
            criteria = criteria && item["Faixa Etaria"] == filtroFaixaEtaria;
        if (filtroSexo != null && filtroSexo != "")
            criteria = criteria && item["Sexo"] == filtroSexo;
        if (filtroRecursoArma != null && filtroRecursoArma != "")
            criteria = criteria && item["RecursoArma"] == filtroRecursoArma;
        if (filtroDistrito != null && filtroDistrito != "")
            criteria = criteria && item["Distrito"] == filtroDistrito;

        return criteria;

    });

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }

    var iconBase = './imagens/iconmapa2.png';

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayResultados.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markers[arrayResultados[i].id - 1].position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[arrayResultados[i].id - 1].title,
            id: markers[arrayResultados[i].id - 1].id,
            visible: true,
            icon: iconBase
        });

    }

    console.log("Foram encontrados " + arrayResultados.length + " elementos de acordo com a busca");

    document.getElementById("contadordebonecos").innerHTML = arrayResultados.length + " / " + jsondata.length;

    const imagens = Array.from({
        length: Number(arrayResultados.length)
    }).reduce((html) => html + imagem, '');
    $('#images').html(imagens);
}

$(document).on("click", "#btnBuscar", botao);
```

Basicamente só queria saber o que é preciso acrescentar para caso volte a clicar no botão re-leia a função toda de novo.

Comment: O seu console.log está mostrando a quantidade correta ou não?

Comment: @AndréVicente sim

Comment: Acredito que esteja criando 2 markers no mesmo lugar. Para tirar o marker vc usa markers[i].setMap(null); . Já tentou no seu for na hora que for mostrar o marker novamente vc colocar markers[arrayResultados[i].id - 1].setMap(map); ? Não consegui testar mas acho que na hora que chama o new google.maps.Marker vc cria uma marker novo.